# What did I do wrong in my question about Windows Update?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, down-votes

I asked the question [Windows Update gives 0x80070643 error on fresh Windows 10 install](https://superuser.com/q/1834067/700114). I provided the steps that led to the issue and the troubleshooting steps I tried to solve it. When people commented on it, I responded and tried their suggestions. One of them did end up solving my problem, so I asked the commenter to post it as an answer so I could accept it. But for some reason, my question is sitting at -3 (0 upvotes and 3 downvotes). What did I do wrong that's leading to so many downvotes?

Comment: Tbh, I don't see anything particularly *wrong* with the question in question. I can't speak for what the downvoters found unacceptable about it

Comment: Probably some people distgrunted about Microsoft believing, that such questions belong to Windows Support. It's just SO syndrome. I hope your problem is solved now.

Comment: I don't think there's any point asking about this as if the downvoters stayed anonymous before they clicked the button, they won't explain their choice at any point most of the time. On a lot of sites of this network you'll find a bunch of people with like 1:5-15 like/dislike ratios, some of which will read one sentence from your question or the title of it and instadownvote because they've seen similar one 50 times and think it's the same issue or something not worthy enough to be asked.